# Natbib ends with Biber error

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am trying to run the example given on [Sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_natbib). I copy/pasted the tex example (1st one of the two available ones) and the bibliography example in a folder and hit compile in TexStudio. I run TexStudio on a MacBook Pro (High Sierra) and configured it to use XeLaTex and Biber.

I though run into the error:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.7
INFO - Logfile is 'doc.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find control file 'doc.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]

What is the problem here?

Comment: natbib needs bibtex not biber, biber is for biblatex

Comment: You are confusing  two completely  different  systems. You should start with  biblatex: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: Ok, I have to compile using bibtex in order to make it work. Works wonderfully now. But why this strange error, telling me to pass "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Comment: @samcarter How can I close this post?

Comment: @Socrates besides the "edit" button is a "close" button at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @samcarter I don't see it. There's share, edit, delete, flag.

Comment: @samcarter And in edit I only have a Save Edits and a Cancel button.

Comment: @Socrates Oh, maybe you don't have enough reputation yet to see the close bottom. In this case, just do nothing.

Comment: Basically this post was solved with the two first comments of DG' and Johannes_B.

Comment: You can delete your post (@samcarter)